# How do I get child data binding to take string instead of parent host property?

Tags: angular

Using Angular 9, why am I getting:

```
 src/app/today-chart/today-chart.component.html:3:50 - error TS2339: Property 'large' does not exist on type 'TodayChartComponent'.

3     <line-chart [curveData]="chart" [graphSize]="large"></line-chart>
```

Why is it expecting `large` to be a host property of the today-chart component? How do I make line-chart's target property `[graphSize]` accept `large` as a string instead of a binded host property of the parent?

today-chart.component.html:

```
<div class="chart-body">
  <div *ngFor="let chart of charts | async | daysFilter:1">
    <line-chart [curveData]="chart" [graphSize]="large"></line-chart>
  </div>
<div>
```

today-chart.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { GetChartDataService } from '../get-chart-data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-today-chart',
  templateUrl: './today-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./today-chart.component.css']
})

export class TodayChartComponent implements OnInit {
  public charts;

  constructor(
    private getChartDataService: GetChartDataService,
    private graphSizeValue: String,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.charts = this.getChartDataService.getData();
  }

}
```

line-chart.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { LineChartService } from './line-chart.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'line-chart',
  templateUrl: './line-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./line-chart.component.css']
})

export class LineChartComponent {
  @Input() curveData: Array<object>;
  @Input()
  get graphSize() {
    return this.graphSizeValue;
  }


  constructor(
    private lineChartService: LineChartService,
    private elRef: ElementRef,
    private graphSizeValue: String,
  ) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.lineChartService.makeGraph(this.curveData, this.elRef.nativeElement);
  }
}
```

---

Comment: Ok so lineChartComponent takes a graphSize as an input and from what Im seeing, large doesnt exist anywhere in your ts file, is this supposed to be a string?

Comment: Did you crete any large variable ? if no try this  [graphSize]="'large'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pass a variable that doesnt exist to an Input which doesnt make sense. I figured you want to pass a string which means you have 2 choices:

```
<line-chart [curveData]="chart" [graphSize]="'large'"></line-chart>
```

or

```
<line-chart [curveData]="chart" graphSize="large"></line-chart>
```

With the bracket, angular is going to search for a variable in your ts file unless you add the single quotes around. Without the bracket, large is going to be taken as a string

Comment: don't answer if typio like that !

Comment: @pc_coder If its just a typo you are right but it very well could be something he didnt understand

Comment: @ukn Thanks, I thought the [] were for one way binding but now I see they are for evaluating the value of `large`. Comping from web components, it seems like Angular should of used a syntax of `graphSize="{{large}}"` for such evaluation instead.